# cbind() on matrices with different lengths

Tags: r, loops, matrix, data-manipulation, summary

I am writing a for loop that converts the output of `summary()` for a set of vectors into a matrix like `foo`, below:

```
            introA   introB  introC  helpA    helpB   helpC
Min.        1        1        4       4       2       4
1st Qu.     5        5        5       5       4       5
Median      5        5        5       5       4       5
Mean        4.83     4.71     4.96    4.89    4.02    4.77
3rd Qu.     5        5        5       5       5       5
Max.        5        5        5       5       5       5
NA's        2        5        0       3       0       2
```

Note that `introC` and `helpB` have zeros in the `NA` row, and that `summary()` does NOT produce this by default - if you call `summary()` on a vector with no `NA` values, the result is an object with length of 6 instead of 7.

My `for` loop initializes an empty matrix `x`, assigns the result of `summary` for each numeric vector in a dataframe to `x`, and binds each `x` to a larger object `y`. This works on all data frames where every vector has no missing values or all of them do.

When some vectors have missing values and others do not, I've written this work-around:

```
x <- matrix(NA,nrow=7,ncol=1)
y <- NULL

for(i in 1:ncol(foo)){

  if(length(summary(foo[,i]==6))){

    x <- as.matrix(c(summary(foo[,i]), 0))
    rownames(x) <- c("Min.", "1st Qu.", "Median", "Mean", "3rd Qu.", "Max.", "NA's")

  }else if(length(summary(foo[,i]==7))){

    x <- as.matrix(summary(foo[,i]))
    rownames(x) <- c("Min.", "1st Qu.", "Median", "Mean", "3rd Qu.", "Max.", "NA's")

  }

  y <- cbind(y,x)
  x <- matrix(NA,nrow=7,ncol=1)
}
```

Here I check to see if the `summary()` of a vector is length 6 or 7, and I add a row when it's not before binding the results together. Outside of my loop, this works. For some reason I get the following error when I try to run this within the loop:

```
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
```

Any idea on how my length could not be equal to the array extent? I have checked the length of `summary()` for all vectors in `foo`; all are either length 6 or 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we put the columns of the `iris` dataset as vectors in the environment, and we put some NAs in one of them :

```
list2env(iris[1:4],envir = globalenv())
Sepal.Length[1:3] <- NA
```

Then:

```
sapply(list(Sepal.Length = Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width = Sepal.Width,Petal.Length = Petal.Length,Petal.Width = Petal.Width),
       function(x) { x <- summary(x); if (is.na(x["NA's"])) x["NA's"] <- 0;x})

#         Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
# Min.        4.300000    2.000000        1.000    0.100000
# 1st Qu.     5.100000    2.800000        1.600    0.300000
# Median      5.800000    3.000000        4.350    1.300000
# Mean        5.862585    3.057333        3.758    1.199333
# 3rd Qu.     6.400000    3.300000        5.100    1.800000
# Max.        7.900000    4.400000        6.900    2.500000
# NA's        3.000000    0.000000        0.000    0.000000
```

Comment: This is conceptually useful - thanks! The main question though - "Any idea on how my length could not be equal to the array extent?" - is the most important for me, because I'm actually working with many more variables and need to make my loop sensitive to changes in different datasets

Comment: your example is not reproducible, I get `Error in ncol(foo) : object 'foo' not found`. If you want us to help you debug we need a reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks - I edited the name of the dataset I have so it's reproducible now. But I also discovered the coding error producing the problem (see my answer below). Accepting yours for the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer: because my `length()` calls were written incorrectly and the condition I wanted to specify was never true. I corrected them to the following...

```
if(length(summary(tueAn[,i]))==6)
```

and

```
if(length(summary(tueAn[,i]))==7)
```

and everything clicked into place. Oof.